# How exactly does Stream Fusion work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The only resources on Stream Fusion I can find are papers introducing it, which aren't really the best learning sources. How exactly does stream fusion work?

More specifially, as this is the part the [paper](http://metagraph.org/papers/stream_fusion.pdf) didn't explain well: how are the co-structures generated after the list->stream conversion (ie, `maps f . maps g`) themselves folded?

Comment: Define "works". Do you want to know how it's correct, how it improves performance, how it's implemented, or a combination thereof?

Comment: Edited for specificity, I want to know how the co-structures are merged, so I can replicate the same on my toy language. The paper isn't clear about that and sometimes it just explains it as "GHC magic". (For anyone following my questions, this is an desperate attempt to improve the compiler for my toy pure functional language, as it seems like there is no fast functional optimizer in the world!)

Comment: Cool, have fun writing an optimizer :-).

Comment: I don't want to :( 
There should be one.

Comment: Jeremy Gibbon's Unfolding Abstract Datatypes provides some detail about the hows and whys around stream-fusion's codata types.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's the definition of `maps` from [Duncan Coutt's thesis](http://community.haskell.org/~duncan/thesis.pdf) (section 1.4.2):

```
maps :: (a → b) → Stream a → Stream b
maps f (Stream next0 s0) = Stream next s0
    where
        next s = case next0 s of
            Done → Done
            Skip s′ → Skip s′
            Yield x s′ → Yield (f x) s′
```

Now consider the expression

```
maps f . maps g
```

A compiler can inline `(.)` to get

```
\x -> maps f (maps g x)
```

We can see from the definition of `Stream` that it has only one constructor:

```
data Stream a = ∃ s . Stream (s → Step a s) s
```

So the previous result is equivalent to:

```
\(Stream next0 s) -> maps f (maps g (Stream next0 s))
```

Inlining `maps g`, which is safe to do as `maps` is non-recursive (this is the key insight of stream fusion):

```
\(Stream next0 s) -> maps f (Stream next1 s)
      where
          next1 s = case next0 s of
            Done → Done
            Skip s′ → Skip s′
            Yield x s′ → Yield (g x) s′
```

Inlining `maps f`:

```
\(Stream next0 s) -> Stream next2 s
      where
          next1 s = case next0 s of
            Done → Done
            Skip s′ → Skip s′
            Yield x s′ → Yield (g x) s′
          next2 s = case next1 s of
            Done → Done
            Skip s′ → Skip s′
            Yield x s′ → Yield (f x) s′
```

Next we can inline `next1` into `next2` and simplify the `case` expressions with "case-of-case" - again note that `next1` is non-recursive - and delete the now dead `next1`:

```
\(Stream next0 s) -> Stream next2 s
      where
          next2 s = case next0 s of
            Done → Done
            Skip s′ → Skip s′
            Yield x s′ → Yield (f (g x)) s′
```

The key point is that these steps are all small optimisations that make sense in isolation and that don't require special compiler knowledge of either stream fusion itself, or the `Stream` type or `maps` function.

Comment: For any other readers, recall that `Stream` is defined as `data Stream a = ∃ s . Stream (s → Maybe (a,s)) s`.

Comment: Thanks - I added the definition of Stream at the appropriate point. Note that the one you give is the simpler variant that doesn't have `Skip`, though the difference isn't important for the perspective of this particular question.

Comment: Just a question on the side here: above in the example after the call to (.) has been inlined: 1) Will the compiler (GHC) inline further here (also inline the call to map, f and g?) 2) If not: Does this mean that each call to map, f and g will result in a "separate thunk" that has to be pulled during runtime and each of these individual calls will produce intermediate datastructures? 3) How good is GHC at performing inlining of functions which intermediate steps are not needed? The way i see it, in this example: Just inline everything and do not produce intermediate structures at all.

Comment: I am refering to this piece of code: `\x -> maps f (maps g x)`

Answer (score 3):

You want to read Peyton Jones' paper on [call pattern specialization](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1291200) which is the engine below the stream fusion libraries. Even further down are [case-of-case](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642397000294) and other optimizations.